# C#:Enable button if datagrid cell value is a number

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

This is the function from Microsoft website to enter only numbers in the datagrid, it works fine.

I want to enable a button if a first cell value of the first row is a number??? How can I do this??

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
        {
            ThermalDatGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "";
            int newInteger;

            // Don't try to validate the 'new row' until finished 
            // editing since there
            // is not any point in validating its initial value.
            if (ThermalDatGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) {
                return;
            }
            if (!int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(),
                out newInteger) || newInteger < 0)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                ThermalDatGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Only Numerical and Non Negative Values";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
if (!int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(),
             out newInteger) || newInteger < 0)
{
   e.Cancel = true;
   ThermalDatGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Only Numerical and Non Negative Values";
}
else
{
   yourButton.Enabled=true;
}
```